# Divi Child Theme Breaks Wordpress Customizer

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, google-chrome, wordpress-theming

I am having an issue with the wordpress customizer and Divi. Customizer works fine with just Divi activated, but when I activate a child theme the customizer suddenly stops working. It displays on the user facing side, but will not render in customizer.

I get this error from Chrome:

> "bpmmarketing.com redirected you too many times."

So I of course made sure my functions file was kosher, which it is.

Here's that code (from elegant themes):

```
<?php

function my_theme_enqueue_styles() {

    $parent_style = 'parent-style';

    wp_enqueue_style( $parent_style, get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-style',
        get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/style.css',
        array( $parent_style ),
        wp_get_theme()->get( 'Version' )
    );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_theme_enqueue_styles' );
?>
```

I am seeing this error in the console:

> load-scripts.php?c=1&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mo…:3
>   GET
>   http://bpmmarketing.com/?customize_changeset_uuid=9610c2a0-37d1-4b5a-abd6-d…ccfb7c&customize_theme=BPM+Marketing&customize_messenger_channel=preview-0
>   net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

We have the site protected right now, but please let me know if you need any other information.

Comment: Did you find this site?
https://wordpress.org/support/topic/err_too_many_redirects-12/. 
The discussion leads to possible bug in WP. Tweaking the permalink structure seems to stop the error - specifically, making sure permalinks are entirely lowercase.

Comment: Fascinating. Plain Permalinks does fix the customizer. So strange. Still not a permanent fix, but there you go.

Answer (score 3):

Your theme folder might contain spaces, for example "Divi child". If so you must change it to "Divi-child" and problem solved.

If not you can set the permalinks to plain as a workaround, but this is not good for SEO.

Comment: This worked for me if anyone else encountered a similar issue. Had spaces in my theme's folder name.

Comment: Yeah, spaces break the customizer. @PeterG child theme name `BPM+Marketing` must be renamed in order to solve this issue.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks.